# Creating new popup window when click button

Tags: c#, popup

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), 
                                   "newWindow",
                                    String.Format("<script>window.open('{0}');</script>",url));
```

I write this code for Pop UP report in new window when I click button, it says "report successfully created" but new window not open.

Comment: It should work perfectly. I don't see any issue with this line.

Comment: check your browser, any popup blocker enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The piece of code is syntactically correct and I don't see any reason why it should not.

**Few things to check**

- The URL is in correct format
- Check for any popup blocker.
- The key name "newWindow" is not already used.

Try to place the code below in Page_load method.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "newWindow", String.Format("<script>window.open('{0}');</script>", "http://www.google.com"));
```

If the above code works the best thing you should do is to make sure that the value of Url is in correct format.

Comment: protected void btnPdf_Click(object sender, DirectEventArgs e) so problem is DirectEventArgs if I take simple EventArgs it works properly but I used Ext.DirectEvent,,so plz help

Comment: thanks,,but I solved this problem

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you called your popup window class "PopupWindow". You created it by right-clicking on your project in project explorer and chosing "Add new Windows Form". Then you added a text box and an "Ok"-Button.

You also added a property to your form so that you can later gain access to the data the user entered in the text box.

```
public class PopupWindow
{
    public string EnteredText
    {
        get
        {
            return( textBox.Text );
        }
    }
}
```

Now you use your new class like this:

```
PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow();

popup.ShowDialog();

string userEnteredText = popup.EnteredText;

popup.Dispose();
```

Comment: I think he uses asp, not forms.